# Compiling C project results in duplicate symbols because of header files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, duplicates

I am trying to compile a C project that I wrote, and a header file has some constant variables. Two .c files are including this header file, however, it results in an error of duplicate symbols.

My project structure is like: **(a => b means b includes a)**

```
common.h => struct.h
struct.h => btree.h
btree.h => btree.c && project.c
```

And related constants that result in an error are staying inside `struct.h`

How should I rebuild the project to avoid this confusion?

My constants look like:

```
const uint32_t NODE_TYPE_SIZE = sizeof(uint8_t);
const uint32_t NODE_TYPE_OFFSET = 0;
const uint32_t IS_ROOT_SIZE = sizeof(uint8_t);
const uint32_t IS_ROOT_OFFSET = NODE_TYPE_SIZE;
const uint32_t PARENT_POINTER_SIZE = sizeof(uint32_t);
const uint32_t PARENT_POINTER_OFFSET = IS_ROOT_OFFSET + IS_ROOT_SIZE;
const uint8_t COMMON_NODE_HEADER_SIZE =
    NODE_TYPE_SIZE + IS_ROOT_SIZE + PARENT_POINTER_SIZE;
```

and `struct.h` has these kinds of variables (around 20 more variables in addition to above) and some structs only.

Comment: Do you have include guards?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Idk what you mean

Comment: Then you have the search term now

Comment: @EugeneSh. Include guards probably won't solve this. Make sure that any objects are *declared* but not *defined* in your header files. Define them in `.c` files. Also, for future reference, please provide a [mre] in your question. I have a pretty good idea what the problem is, but usually more information will be needed.

Comment: @Harun ŞAŞMAZ You can declare the constants with storage class static.

Comment: @KeithThompson I added some of those variables seemed in error traceback.

Comment: @ryyker I was using before knowing they are called header guards lol, habits. Vlad has a point, declaring them static resolved the issue. I guess it is a binding error?

Comment: Making them static is one solution. Another is to declare them `extern` in the header *without* initializations, and define them with initializations in the corresponding `.c` file. Header guards alone won't fix the linking problem if you have more than one `.c` file in your program that includes the header. Each non-`static` object has to be defined just once in the entire program.

Comment: @HarunŞAŞMAZ no you should not define any read data in the header files only in the .c source files. Read my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is definitely not the solution only dirty workaround.

Comment: @P__J__ I mentioned two possibilities. Which one are you saying is a "dirty workaround"?

Comment: @KeithThompson `static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define constants in the .h files. Declare them only as `extern`

example:

```
extern const uint32_t NODE_TYPE_SIZE;
```

Then define them in the .c file.

BTW those variables do not make any sense they should be a macros instead.

```
#define NODE_TYPE_SIZE sizeof(uint8_t)
```

Same with all other similar constants. Otherwise if they have to be accessed from different compilation units, they will be stored in the memory and read from it, having negative performance impact.

Answer (score -4):

You could use `#DEFINE STRUCTDEF` in `struct.h`, and `#DEFINE BTREEDEF` in `btree.h`. This will enable the compiler to check for these definitions in `struct.h` and `btree.h`, using `#IFDEF STRUCTDEF`,or `#IFNDEF STRUCTDEF`, etc.. then take appropriate action to enclose the duplicates between the `#XXXX` blocks so that they only get included once.

Comment: I have edited to make the code and file objects you cited stand out.  But you should consider deleting this post as its content is not really addressing the stated needs in question. (I am not DV-er)